# Burning 20 amp breaker

Tags: circuit-breaker

I have a plug in hot tub on a 15amp GFCI outlet (120V).  The cord for the hot tub and outlet have GFCI.  I have tested the outlet and it works fine.  The breaker started getting hot and burned out.  I replaced it, plugged in the hot tub, and the new one started burning too.  Outlet and plug still did not trip.  Other than some outdoor lighting there are a few outlets on this circuit but nothing plugged in other than hot tub. How can the breaker burn out without the outlet tripping?  The breaker is a 20amp Siemens.  It was in the bar tightly and the hot wire is well connected.  The tub has been running more often lately but I don't want to call HT repair if there is an electrical problem.  I would love some help here.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you pulled the breaker before could you pull the breaker and take a photo of the connection tab? Siemens breakers are not one of the brands that are known for problems but if at some point if there was damage to the buss it will only get worse, this is a single 15 amp 120v circuit I am guessing? 14 awg wire since you said you had other devices on it it is probably overloaded but We do need more information to assist.

Comment: What make and model is the *panel*? Can you post photos of the labeling on the inside of the panel's door please, as well as the situation with the damaged breaker jaw and busbar stab?